# Shrink data file corruption risks?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, corruption

Are there any risks of data file corruption resulting from shrinking sql data files?

Comment: Shrink is single threaded and causes massive fragmentation. see [why shrinking your data files is a bad idea](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, shrink is safe. Unless you hit some bug in SQL Server of course, but that can happen whatever you do. The shrinkage is done as a series of mini transactions and it is also safe to terminate the operation.

There are of course other disadvantages of doing shrink, but I take it that you are aware of those.